# Разные базовые шаблоны для SPA Angular

Tags: angular2

Добрый день. У меня нет опыта построения приложений на Angular и нужен совет. Когда например я строю приложение на php mvc фреймворке, я использую один базовый шаблон для публичной части сайта, второй для админки, третий для личного кабинета пользователя и т.д... В Ангуляре я не могу найти как реализовать подобную схему. Тут я вижу один базовый шаблон в котором композируются компоненты со своими шаблонами. И как то, что то похожее можно сделать, как я вижу только через роутер, но все равно это решит задачу только частично отрисовывая все через один шаблон, и мне видится не простой задачей компоновка сайдбаров, футеров, хедеров, для каждого раздела сайта, использующего другой дизайн(другой шаблон). Возможно я что то не дочитал в документации. Кто компетентен не сочтите за труд дать совет.

Answer (score 1):

В Angular можно готовить по разному. Если мы говорим про Single Page Application (SPA), то в Angular есть модульность из коробки, каждый модуль может полностью независимым от других, и при этом можно сделать пару модулей для в котором будут типовые элементы, и модуль который будет единственным в системе, ядром, например с единой системой логирования и авторизации.

Готовить можно по разному, на сколько фантазии хватает.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, вникаю в систему модулей.

Comment: Перечитал https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule. Нет там не одного слова про то как использовать разные базовые шаблоны. Там что такое модули, как их использовать. Но базовый файл index.html один для всех модулей. Точно как и файл стилей (или файлы) для этого файла одни и те же. Получается что тот вопрос который я поднял в топике не решается просто использованием модулей. Можно сделать для каждого раздела сайта группу рутов в роутере и на компонент содержащий router-outlet цеплять базовоый шаблон с дизайном раздела сайта. Это то что я пока нашел... Но это не зависимо в одном это модуле или разных

Comment: Вы ведь разные части сайта планируете держать по разным путям роутинга? `index.html` и будет только содержать `<router-outlet>`. В модулях же будет своя собственный роутинг, где все пути добавлены через `RouterModule.forChild()`.
А в модулях свой центральный контролер, в котором и делайте все разметку для модуля страницы как вам вздумается.

Comment: Спасибо, зарывшись в доки я пришел к таким же выводам....